# Javascript only works in Chrome and not Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

For some reason, this piece of code work just find in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I have no idea why, so I hope someone can help me.

The div "slideshow" and it's content wont show at all in Firefox. It's like the JS is not even loaded.

HTML

```
<div id="slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow_text">
                <p class="txt1">Er du klar?</p>
                <p class="txt2">til et <span>NYT</span></p>
                <p class="txt3">&</p>
                <p class="txt4">BEDRE <span>JEG</span>?</p>
            </div>
            <img id="slide_1" src="img/ss/large_slide1.jpg" alt="Woman">
            <img id="slide_2" src="img/ss/large_slide2.jpg" alt="Woman">
            <img id="slide_3" src="img/ss/large_slide3.jpg" alt="Woman">
        </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slide_1").animate({left: 0}, 700);

$(".slideshow_text").slideDown("slow");

$("#slide_1").click(function() {
    $("#slide_1").animate({left: "-980px"}, 700);
    $("#slide_2").animate({left: 0}, 700);
    $("#slide_3").css("left", "980px");
});
$("#slide_2").click(function() {
    $("#slide_2").animate({left: "-980px"}, 700);
    $("#slide_3").animate({left: 0}, 700);
    $("#slide_1").css("left", "980px");
});

$("#slide_3").click(function() {
    $("#slide_3").animate({left: "-980px"}, 700);
    $("#slide_1").animate({left: 0}, 700);
    $("#slide_2").css("left", "980px");
});

});
```

CSS

```
#slideshow {
width: 980px;
height: 445px;
margin: 50px auto 25px auto;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

#slide_1, #slide_2, #slide_3 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 980px;
}

.slideshow_text {
display: none;
width: 200px;
background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.4);
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 650px;
z-index: 9;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 15px;
}

.slideshow_text p{
float: left;
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

If you need more details, let me know. Frankly I don't really know what else to write.

Comment: What do you see when you look in the JavaScript console in Firefox?

Comment: I see this: [13:20:24.356] SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead @ http://localhost:8383/WebProeve1/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:1

Comment: That's just a warning and won't be breaking your code. To fix, in jquery-1.10.2.min.js, find and remove the line `//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map`

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you put a width and height on your images?

```
#slide_1, #slide_2, #slide_3 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 980px;
height: 445px;
width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Adding a width and height did not help.

Answer (score 0):

What **version of jQuery** are you using?  If you use jQuery 1.9.1 it will work in FireFox, however, with jQuery 2.0.2 it will not [at least checking with an older browser it did not]

[Check out this example I created](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ps6Ya/3/) based on your code [no code changed, just using jQuery 1.9.1], does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was my "#wrapper" that collapsed on it self, hiding all the content within.

Adding a height did not do the trick, but adding a border did the trick and the content would show.